# how to animate UIPopiverController to slide from offscreen to onscreen

Tags: ios

in iOS 5.0, is it possible to animate the UIpopoverController to slide in from offscreen to onscreen whenever it needs to appear..

Thanks for your help on this...

Comment: Not really. The nature of a popover is that it "pops over" an existing UI element, typically originating from the disclosing UI element (a button). Why not just use a regular or modal view animated in from the side?

Comment: i see..... to answer your question, i cannot use modal as i need to allow touch interaction with the views lying below this popover view which is possible with the popover view but not with modal.. I can use a regular view though but will have to construct the border and title that popoverview gives me....